# Nested Logging in Junit

Tags: java, junit5, java.util.logging

I am writing nested tests using Junit, and would love to write logs in individual tests that only show up while viewing the log for that test. Currently all logs show up at the top of the hierarchy.
I am not as familiar with customizing the logging frameworks, so any help would be appreciated!

I tried searching the documentation, but only found information about writing nested classes themselves.

I also tried instantiating loggers with the nested class, but it still shows each log at the top level of the test hierarchy.

Comment: I understand that people log in production code, but why do you want to log in tests? Tests should either pass or fail. Manually inspecting logs defeats the purpose of automated tests. Either way, please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].